# How to check if any of the elements in a list can be found in the given string?

Tags: python, list, if-statement

This is the way I'm doing it, but I'm wondering if there's a better way. When I google the problem it suggests using list comprehensions or any() method which either doesn't work for me or I'm misunderstanding them. But I gathered that they just give out boolean values - but I want to keep on using the matched URL if one of the phrases is located in it.

```
for URL in URLs
    if 'phrase1' in URL or 'phrase2' in URL or 'phrase3' in URL:
        get_subcategories(URL)               #Calling a function wit the matched URL 
        ...
```

Comment: _When I google the problem it suggests using list comprehensions or any() method which either doesn't work for me or I'm misunderstanding them._ Please show the code you tried using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a list of phrases to check to iterate over:

```
phrases = ['phrase1', ...]

if any(phrase in URL for phrase in phrases):
    ...
```